# Need to subset a dataset in SAS based on two variables

Tags: sas, subset

I have a complex dataset and need to pull unique individuals who might have multiple observations for different reasons. Here is an example of how to the data is organized:

```
id caseid employerid
1  1      1
1  1      2
1  2      1
1  2      2
2  1      1
3  1      1
3  2      1
```

Basically individuals have a unique id but could be in multiple cases and could also have multiple employers. I want to remove duplicates by caseid but not by employerid for each individual and I am not sure how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect as your output? In general, I use SQL for this and use MAX/MIN. If the max is equal to the min then the values are the same across all, excluding missing otherwise there are multiple. Or use Count Distinct.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use COUNT DISTINCT to find the number of caseID and employerID per ID
2. Filter it based on a WHERE query
3. Isolate all records from your have table based on #2.

   ```
   proc sql;
   create table _filtered as 
   select id, count(distinct caseID) as n_caseID, count(distinct employerID) as n_employerID
   from have;
   order by 1, 2, 3;
   quit;


   proc sql;
   create table want as
   select *
   from have where ID in 
         (select ID from _filtered where n_caseID=1);
   quit;
   ```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get this to work by using 'group by id' instead of 'order by 1,2,3', but I still want to keep those with multiple caseids I just only want to keep one caseid because there is currently just a duplicate of the data under additional caseids if that makes sense. This appears to only be keeping those with only 1 caseid.

Comment: You said subset, which I interpret as a filter operation. Sounds like instead you want to identify those records then it would be merge, not a subset or filter.